# IntelliJ Kotest doesn't show tests failed with exception

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotest

## Code

I have the following three tests:

```
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.BehaviorSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe

class Example {
    fun blah(number: Int): Int {
        if (number == 1) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        } else {
            return number
        }
    }
}

class ExampleTest : BehaviorSpec({
    Given("example") {
        val example = Example()
        When("calling blah(0)") {
            val result = example.blah(0)
            Then("it returns 0") {
                result shouldBe 0
            }
        }
        When("calling blah(1)") {
            val result = example.blah(1)
            Then("it returns 1") {
                result shouldBe 1
            }
        }
        When("calling blah(2)") {
            val result = example.blah(2)
            Then("it returns 2") {
                result shouldBe 2
            }
        }
    }

})
```

## Problem

The middle test throws an exception which is not expected. I would expect to see 3 tests run, 1 of which failed, but what IntelliJ and Kotest plugin show me is that 2 out of 2 tests passed. I can see in the Test Results side panel that something is not right, but it doesn't have any useful information.

If I navigate to the `index.html` with tests results, I can see everything correctly. I would like to see the same data in IntelliJ.

## Screenshots

**IntelliJ output:**
[image: IntellijOutput]
Note that:

- on the left the test for number 1 is missing
- at the top it says "Tests passed: 2 of 2"
- on the left there are yellow crosses up to "Given", but all tests in "Given" are green

**`index.html` with the test results:**
[image: Tests result in html]

## Other information

- Kotest version: 4.6.3
- IntelliJ Kotest plugin version: 1.1.49-IC-2021.2.3

[image: IntelliJ Kotest plugin]

Comment: Which version of kotest

Comment: kotest version 4.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is resolved in `5.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception is thrown inside the `Given` or `When` block, the test initialisation fails. Here is the output if I run that one test only:

[image: Failing test]

It seems that exceptions are only handled inside the `Then` blocks.

This means that everything that can throw an exception should go into `Then` blocks, which in turn means that setup and action cannot be shared between the tests:

```
class ExampleTest : BehaviorSpec({
    Given("example") {
        When("calling blah(0)") {
            Then("it returns 0") {
                val example = Example()
                val result = example.blah(0)
                result shouldBe 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    Given("example") {
        When("calling blah(1)") {
            Then("it returns 1") {
                val example = Example()
                val result = example.blah(1)
                result shouldBe 1
            }
        }
    }

    Given("example") {
        When("calling blah(2)") {
            Then("it returns 2") {
                val example = Example()
                val result = example.blah(2)
                result shouldBe 2
            }
        }
    }

})
```

This also results in 2 levels of redundant indentation.

An alternative to the above code is to use different [kotest testing style](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/testing-styles.html), for example `ShouldSpec`.